# Value conversation in C#

Tags: c#, datatable

I want to assign one col value of datatable to another col of same datatable
like:

```
objdt.Rows[i]["mr_discrepancy_cd1s"].ToString()=objdt.Rows[i["mr_discrepancy_cd1"].ToString();
```

How Could I Do This?

Answer (score 1):

We can fetch the index off the column in the `DataTable` using the Ordinal property and we can replace the values as follows:

```
objdt.Rows[i][objdt.Columns["ColumnName"].Ordinal] = objdt.Rows[i][objdt.Columns["ColumnName"].Ordinal]
```

or

```
objdt.Rows[i][objdt.Columns[objdt.Columns[1].ColumnName].Ordinal] =
                    objdt.Rows[i][objdt.Columns[objdt.Columns[2].ColumnName].Ordinal]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
objdt.Rows[i]["mr_discrepancy_cd1s"] =objdt.Rows[i]["mr_discrepancy_cd1"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `ToString`, it will convert every value to a string even if it wasn't a string before. That'll change the type and can even change the data. It'll also blow up if the column in the datarow is `null`.

Instead use the strongly typed [`Field` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.field(v=vs.90).aspx) which also supports nullables.

Presuming that it is really a `string` in this case:

```
DataRow row = objdt.Rows[i];
string mr_discrepancy_cd1 = row.Field<string>("mr_discrepancy_cd1");
row.SetField("mr_discrepancy_cd1s", mr_discrepancy_cd1);
```